# Is the use of ethernet cables/RJ45's appropriate for high frequency applications (3GB/s, 1.5GHz )

Tags: rf, analog, embedded, digital-communications

I am looking into using a GMSL2 serializer/deserializer pair for using a CSI camera at long distances from a computer. The GMSL2 channel specifications give the following information:

[image]

Firstly, I'm not entirely sure what the F1/2 linkrate is and how it's relevant.
Secondly,  the GMSL2 guidelines specify that the link should be impedance matched for 100Ω when using STP. Google has told me that CAT8 cable is rated to 40GPs at 2000MHz, so it appears to meet the channel requirements in that regard, However, I'm struggling to find information on RJ45 connectors. Do they typically have a characteristic impedance of 100 ohms? Should I be concerned if they do not? I've read that if the connection is not impedance matched you can have reflections which can cause disruptions.

Any information would be appreciated!

Comment: It means the frequency of a single-direction link (either in one direction of the other) hence, it gets the "1/2" inserted. and for 3GBps, the maximum frequency will be 1.5 GHz.

Comment: Cables are qualified to different standards (the CAT  designations).  While great for digital data and noise rejection, twisted pair has some annoying implications with current flow and analog waveform signals, which is why coax is used for those purposes.  Reflection behaves like necking down or up pipe- extra swirls at necking mess with power transmitted.  While it can get very bad in some cases depending on feedback involved, you might not see too big an issue for your typical use case depending on lengths of cable and current involved.  For best results go digital over ethernet cables...

Comment: What is "long" in this case? And technically, there are no Ethernet cables, there are only cables with specific category cables and connectors that can be used for Ethernet too, and RJ45 is not a connector or even an existing standard for registered jacks, but just incorrectly used terminology for what are really 8P8C modular connectors. Are you sure GMSL2 does not require coax?

Comment: Looking at a random cat8 datasheet, it specs 3dB attenuation per meter at 2 GHz. That is going to severely limit your max length. Probably you want to use something with better high frequency performance.

Comment: Thanks everyone for your responses:

Comment: @user1850479, by long I only mean 3 meters max, so I believe 3dB/m might actually be fine.

Comment: @Abel, I believe GMSL2 is a digital communication protocol.

Comment: @Justme the GMSL2 hardware design guidelines provided by AnalogDevices specifies that it can be used with STP. Long is only around 3m. Am I correct in saying that RJ-45 refers to the wiring pattern, while 8P8C refers to the actual connector?

Comment: @Harrison Even if it says STP, you might want to use an STP cable that suits your purpose rather than using one pair of CAT8. And like I said, RJ-45 is not anything in any standard, people just use the term incorrectly in daily life. RJ standards define telecom network interfaces with specific connector (the wall jack) and specific wiring patterns for specific use, such as RJ11 for a telephone. RJ45 is not on that list. The connector is a modular connector, and Ethernet uses a specific modular connector with 8P8C configuration, wiring defined in TIA-568.